# How to assign values to a column of a dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
POSITION    Code_Count
   S1       {"[471E;1]"}
   S2       {"[471E;1]"}
   S3       {"[471E;1]"} 
   S4       {"[471E;1]"}
   S5       {"[471E;1]"}
   S6       {"[5812;1]"}
   S7       {"[471E;1]"}
   S8       {"[471E;1]"}
   T1       {"[7A2A;1]"}
   T2       {"[471E;1]"}
   T3       {"[7C95;1]"}
   T4       {"[471E;1]"}
   T5       {"[471E;1]"}
   T6       {"[471E;1]"}
   T7       {"[471E;1]"}
   T8       {"[471E;1]"}
```

In the Code_Count column the first string is a code and the number is the count.
Furthermore, the codes are classified into 4 categories A through D. The list of all the codes present in the categories is given below:
The codes are classified into 4 categories say A through D as follows:

Category A contains these codes:  7749   7783    7784    7786    7A14    7AC5    7C88    7C92    7C93    7C95    C749    C783    C784    C786    CA14    CAC5    CC88    CC92    CC93    CC95    442A    49C2

Category B has these codes:  1D  32  430B    4415    448E    4490    4492    457A    457B    496C    4970    778A    7A09    7A2A    7A2C    7C7C    7C80    C78A    CA09    CA2A    CA2C

Category C has these codes:  7A7F    7A80    7C7E    CA7F    CA80    CAC8    7AC8    C77E    445A    496E    471E    49CA

Category D: 7AF0    7AF1    7AF2    7AF3    CAF0    CAF1    CAF2    CAF3    4616    4617    4618    5812

I would like for my final dataframe to contain the counts of codes to corresponding positions according to the codes present in the initial dataframe by sorting them out according to the Category they belong to. For example, the output dataframe according to the above dataframe should be:

```
POSITION    Category A     Category B      Category C     Category D
   S1           0              0               1              0
   S2           0              0               1              0
   S3           0              0               1              0
   S4           0              0               1              0
   S5           0              0               1              0
   S6           0              0               0              1
   S7           0              0               1              0
   S8           0              0               1              0
   T1           0              1               0              0
   T2           0              0               1              0
   T3           1              0               0              0
   T4           0              0               1              0
   T5           0              0               1              0
   T6           0              0               1              0
   T7           0              0               1              0
   T8           0              0               1              0
```

I have tried using str.contains method but without any success. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why are there curly braces around the values in column `Code_Count`? Is the whole thing a string, perhaps like so: `'{"[471E;1]"}'`?

Comment: No. That is pulled from an SQL query probably and is a format or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can extract values by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) first and then add `Count` by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) with mask created by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html). Last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) unnecessary columns and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) `0`:

```
catA = ['7749','7783','7784','7786','7A14','7AC5','7C88','7C92','7C93','7C95','C749','C783','C784','C786','CA14','CAC5','CC88','CC92','CC93','CC95','442A','49C2']
catB = ['1D','32','430B','4415','448E','4490','4492','457A','457B','496C','4970','778A','7A09','7A2A','7A2C','7C7C','7C80','C78A','CA09','CA2A','CA2C']
catC = ['7A7F','7A80','7C7E','CA7F','CA80','CAC8 7AC8 C77E','445A','496E','471E','49CA']
catD = ['7AF0','7AF1','7AF2','7AF3','CAF0','CAF1','CAF2','CAF3','4616','4617','4618','5812']
```

---

```
df[['Code','Count']] = df.Code_Count.str.strip('{["]}').str.split(';', expand=True)
df['Category A'] = df.ix[df.Code.isin(catA), 'Count']
df['Category B'] = df.ix[df.Code.isin(catB), 'Count']
df['Category C'] = df.ix[df.Code.isin(catC), 'Count']
df['Category D'] = df.ix[df.Code.isin(catD), 'Count']
df.drop(['Code_Count', 'Code', 'Count'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df[['Category A','Category B','Category C','Category D']] = 
df[['Category A','Category B','Category C','Category D']].fillna(0)
print (df)
   POSITION Category A Category B Category C Category D
0        S1          0          0          1          0
1        S2          0          0          1          0
2        S3          0          0          1          0
3        S4          0          0          1          0
4        S5          0          0          1          0
5        S6          0          0          0          1
6        S7          0          0          1          0
7        S8          0          0          1          0
8        T1          0          1          0          0
9        T2          0          0          1          0
10       T3          1          0          0          0
11       T4          0          0          1          0
12       T5          0          0          1          0
13       T6          0          0          1          0
14       T7          0          0          1          0
15       T8          0          0          1          0
```

Comment: I am facing a weird problem. All the values are being displayed as 0. Before entering the fillna(0), all of them are being displayed as NaNs. Any idea why this is happening? Thank you very much!

Comment: All values? There are no `1` in your output? Or you get `NaN` instead `0` before `fillna` ?

Comment: Yes, there is no 1 in the output. Even before fillna, all the values are NaNs.

Comment: What is `type(df.ix[0, 'Code_Count'])` ?

Comment: It is 'str'. String.

Comment: super, I was afraid it is `dict`. So what return `df[['Code','Count']] = df.Code_Count.str.strip('{["]}').str.split(';', expand=True)` ? It get two columns - one for code and another for count?

Comment: Yes, two columns Code and Count are made. But the dataframe is filled with NaNs in both the columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128422/discussion-between-ruffy26-and-jezrael).